# WebGL uniform1i transform

Tags: webgl

I'm studying webgl and I came across this line with regards to a texture:

```
gl.uniform1i(uniformLocation, -4)
```

A basic rgba texture buffer has been bound. What exactly would the location shift above do?

Comment: What is a "location shift" shift? `gl.uniform1i` just stores the value into the uniform variable with the given location in the default uniform block of the currently bound shader.

Comment: @Rabbid76 - Sorry, i'm still learning. It seems like the -4 shifts the texture, versus using some other value. I guess the shader math does something with -4? What's a typical value to pass for something like this?

Comment: There is no "typical value". This instruction just initializes a variable. What happens to this variable and how its value is used depends on the shader program.

Comment: if your uniform location refers to a sampler in a shader the value specifies which texture unit to sample from, I have no idea what happens when you pass in negative values since texture units are positive integers, maybe it just selects texture unit 4 and ignores the sign.